# Celery: How to abort running task

Tags: python, redis, celery

**calculator.py**

```
def add(n):
    r = n + n
    time.sleep(15) # long running task
    return r
```

**tasks.py**

```
from calculator import add

REDIS_URL = redis://redis:6379/0

celery_app = Celery(__name__, broker=REDIS_URL, backend=REDIS_URL)

@celery_app.task(bind=True, name="background_task_job", base=AbortableTask)
def background_task_job(self, n):
    abt = "Aborted"
    val = 0
    
    while not self.is_aborted():
        
        val = add(n)  # ADD() which calls sleep_one() 
        return val
    
    return abt
```

**app.py**

```
from tasks import background_task_job


# On Start button
result = background_task_job.apply_async(args=(2,))


# On Cancel button
abortable_task = AbortableAsyncResult(result.id)
abortable_task.abort()
```

**Observed:**
I clicked start button, background task started running. Say after 8 seconds (for eg) I clicked cancel button, I observed no "Aborted" message but the inside add() seems to be alive/running, As after, 7 more seconds which makes 15 seconds [8 + 7] I observed celery returns outputs as 4 [celery| success 15.0sec 4] (for eg).

1.
Why **add()** not getting aborted which is inside the **background_task_job()**?
What I am missing?

2.
If so output is returned as 4, why [celery| success **15.0sec** 4] and not **8sec** as I clicked cancel button at 8 seconds? Is this behavior correct?

Please suggest.

**Updated: C**ode

After replacing `time.sleep()` with `sleep_one()`, I am able to get state and status of the task as **ABORTED**, but still the function runs completely and didnot get aborted.

```
def sleep_one(n):
    start = time.time()
    finish = start + 4
    while time.time() < finish:
        pass
    return n
```

```
def add(n):
    # time.sleep(15)
    n = 0
   # simulating long running process
    n += sleep_one(1)
    n += sleep_one(1)
    n += sleep_one(1)
    n += sleep_one(1)
    n += sleep_one(1)
    n += sleep_one(1)
    n += sleep_one(1)
    n += sleep_one(1)
    n += sleep_one(1)
    n += sleep_one(1)
    n += sleep_one(1)
    n += sleep_one(1)
    n += sleep_one(1)
    n += sleep_one(1)
    n += sleep_one(1)
    return n
```

What I am missing?

As while searching, I came across small sample codes only in which there is direct `for loop` inside the `background_task_job()`.
Since, I am calling `add()` inside the `background_task_job()` does it affect or prevent the task from getting aborted?

Comment: Pretty sure that it's because of `time.sleep(15)` call which "hangs" interpreter. Try to replace it with dozen of `sleep(1)`.

Comment: Hi Olvin, I tried replacing `time.sleep(15)` with 15 `sleep(1)` but still getting the same result.